# Cannot center products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend

I have a problem. I want to center my products on my page because I have only two but that what I am doing is not working. I tried this:

```
ul.products{
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

What I can do to center products? Here's my page [link](http://befreeborstel.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in your css file:

```
/* Center product on pages */
ul.products {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    width: 70%!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important;
}

.page-template-template-homepage-php .site-main .columns-4 ul.products li.product, .site-main .columns-4 ul.products li.product {
    width: 44.73913%!important;
}
```